# How to run SageMaker Distributed training from SageMaker Studio?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, distributed-training, amazon-machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker-studio

The sample notebooks for **SageMaker Distributed training**, like here: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/advanced_functionality/distributed_tensorflow_mask_rcnn/mask-rcnn-scriptmode-s3.ipynb rely on the `docker build .` and `docker push .` commands, which are not available or installable in [Amazon SageMaker Studio](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/studio/).

Are there alternatives of these notebooks that are compatible with the SageMaker Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SageMaker Studio does not support Docker, since the Studio apps are containers themselves. You can use the SageMaker Docker Build tool to build docker images from Studio (uses CodeBuild in the backend). See the blog [Using the Amazon SageMaker Studio Image Build CLI to build container images from your Studio notebooks](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/using-the-amazon-sagemaker-studio-image-build-cli-to-build-container-images-from-your-studio-notebooks/) and the [Github repo](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-studio-image-build-cli) for details.